# Updating docker container with new image version but keeping configs

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, software-update

I have [phpmyadmin](/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin) Docker's container that runs an older version of phpMyAdmin. I need to update the phpMyAdmin to the latest version. The common solution here is to stop the current container and then getting the latest image of the [phpMyAdmin](https://hub.docker.com/_/phpmyadmin) then initiate a new container from it.

**However** this solution, *as it is*, is not suitable for me, because I modified the configurations of the current container before, I installed some additional themes, etc so I want to keep (at least) the configurations after update, such as networking ports, etc.

Is there any way to keep the configurations of the old container to be used in the new updated container?

### Update

The following is a screen shot ftom `docker inspect`
[image]

The full output of inspect:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "b53734ca90b06ac6b109f91ecedec7c51b32f9dff88822c86a1a8e03e2a49841",
        "Created": "2021-12-15T21:36:44.645730545Z",
        "Path": "/docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "apache2-foreground"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 2079,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2024-01-11T15:47:11.107791099Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2024-01-10T21:56:07.409001Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:ccebddf114742e63f84ba9c90afeb75719c3f92c17e30e4a4ad98c8cd1af8aef",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b53734ca90b06ac6b109f91ecedec7c51b32f9dff88822c86a1a8e03e2a49841/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b53734ca90b06ac6b109f91ecedec7c51b32f9dff88822c86a1a8e03e2a49841/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b53734ca90b06ac6b109f91ecedec7c51b32f9dff88822c86a1a8e03e2a49841/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b53734ca90b06ac6b109f91ecedec7c51b32f9dff88822c86a1a8e03e2a49841/b53734ca90b06ac6b109f91ecedec7c51b32f9dff88822c86a1a8e03e2a49841-json.log",
        "Name": "/phpmyadmin",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "foxNet",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8888"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "unless-stopped",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6d338fbcdf1985b48f584b9868f77f9583bd84baa2fb5ed521b888a2173a7ca9-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/85da6fd0d388892dc8aec990fc310255d98b1f61f494a57c082a6e7074f4784d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d5f33040e099ec5da595aa94042000c23c12a5c81cc2add7ff1c1e0d495359ee/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/496f7e735af2ecc05491a0f13be63f9c723e950ca103e9b4059bd224dd2fb767/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/689ad3ccfbd7e9f12f8efac651edb546d669ab455822691bfd6e6a3ad6d90bcd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a1ca1e7ccd31220558324aa268cdc3104c1220fd6ddfdcedb6e43642411a1f38/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ae2c9d26dc4a0e4d15e0f5dd26314d9bf4c7ee565a09cd5cdd383acf347fb436/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/13acc7001aabc2db85644e7b9fae1d5a8bfe0e8fed6adccf032d28ddf0922366/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6ad01c4feb1a6fd1ad87d776c93c2db27eb83cba79fefe8bd37ea7ae87c06efe/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/055801826e3e95f2b778eccad7b23b8c97191279201fcf90649c087a60555939/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/80a97f0a5257be077dd931aca1e3a426b984794a7f019e9bdbc05608bb7a3c28/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/228511c37bfd270d481c887dcd833059088bbc8df62104cd2b9e89ae9e2e6573/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c67aa89ecac044e327d7c944008e57357cfcd89150897e8cbb5b799df01484e5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5eb0ac794ad6a64fff53a015e0a8402f048b13c1ace30b7f8433aba683578229/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c7220562a5b72365b3ebabf212e12d2a13cc205caf799bb250718e507572e68a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/69a5b0c6473beeea7bbef1463720a189528fc720b18746c0445d7c392bb4eec9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/704d94421af179cbee366b267720d9292949e8b5a469e8d58e47cead5637f368/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5f0c83690a6548b850f049dd9ade4d77a5257273bc6e2dd8cb226db2405ecd92/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/66785b710f9eb42218a8432db318d3d5118904dcc8a56763dc9eeca9bb90d66f/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6d338fbcdf1985b48f584b9868f77f9583bd84baa2fb5ed521b888a2173a7ca9/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6d338fbcdf1985b48f584b9868f77f9583bd84baa2fb5ed521b888a2173a7ca9/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6d338fbcdf1985b48f584b9868f77f9583bd84baa2fb5ed521b888a2173a7ca9/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "b53734ca90b0",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf \t\tdpkg-dev \t\tfile \t\tg++ \t\tgcc \t\tlibc-dev \t\tmake \t\tpkg-config \t\tre2c",
                "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
                "APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2",
                "APACHE_ENVVARS=/etc/apache2/envvars",
                "PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
                "PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
                "PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -pie",
                "GPG_KEYS=42670A7FE4D0441C8E4632349E4FDC074A4EF02D 5A52880781F755608BF815FC910DEB46F53EA312",
                "PHP_VERSION=7.4.26",
                "PHP_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.26.tar.xz",
                "PHP_ASC_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.26.tar.xz.asc",
                "PHP_SHA256=e305b3aafdc85fa73a81c53d3ce30578bc94d1633ec376add193a1e85e0f0ef8",
                "MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=600",
                "MEMORY_LIMIT=512M",
                "UPLOAD_LIMIT=2048K",
                "VERSION=5.1.1",
                "SHA256=1964d7190223c11e89fa1b7970c618e3a3bae2e859f5f60383f64c3848ef6921",
                "URL=https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/5.1.1/phpMyAdmin-5.1.1-all-languages.tar.xz"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "apache2-foreground"
            ],
            "Image": "phpmyadmin",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/var/www/html",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "org.opencontainers.image.authors": "The phpMyAdmin Team <developers@phpmyadmin.net>",
                "org.opencontainers.image.description": "Run phpMyAdmin with Alpine, Apache and PHP FPM.",
                "org.opencontainers.image.documentation": "https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker#readme",
                "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "GPL-2.0-only",
                "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker.git",
                "org.opencontainers.image.title": "Official phpMyAdmin Docker image",
                "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker#readme",
                "org.opencontainers.image.vendor": "phpMyAdmin",
                "org.opencontainers.image.version": "5.1.1"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGWINCH"
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "d7f131eb72abe84e8bdac15be4180406e6c6c7c247b90b74343cf21a56d2c6d3",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8888"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "8888"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/d7f131eb72ab",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "foxNet": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": [
                        "mysql:db"
                    ],
                    "Aliases": [
                        "b53734ca90b0"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "1e3427aacb8ffb79404adfecfc63a51e6da994bc3ff9988a4c66bcf647f82e63",
                    "EndpointID": "dcd0476d65f4e6899d782d7e462e6d68a894237dba94b25b5b28ef04cc653906",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Which variant of the container did you use?

Comment: How did you modify the configurations? For docker, networking and ports should be fed into the container with variables or docker params. For php, their recommended way is linking a local file into the container like with `-v /mystuff/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php` without actually messing with the container itself. Other changes would go to the DB in a separate container. If you stuck to those methods, you can replace it easily. Anything else will need to be manually redone or copied over

Comment: @Ramhound I use the `apache2-foreground`

Comment: That isn’t one of the variants listed on the website

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, please checkout the update in which a full copy of `docker inspect` output is added.